# Android ADB locks up debugging over bluetooth

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I have managed to configure ADB to connect to a phone over bluetooth (i am unable to use wifi). However, as soon as the phone is connected ADB seems to lock up typing "ADB logcat" doesn't display anything and I have to ctrl 'C' out of it. Typing ADB devices shows the device as being connected. Has anyone got any ideas?